Can the One-Sided Mann-Whitney U Test Have a Composite Null Hypothesis?
Let's say there's an i.i.d. sample $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_{n_1}$ from a distribution with the CDF $F$ and $Y_1, Y_2, \ldots, Y_n$ from a distribution whose CDF is $G$.
As far as I know, the null hypothesis of the two-sided Mann-Whitney U test is that $F=G$, while the alternative is that $F \neq G$.
However, what if I want to do a one-sided test? For example, I could specify the alternative hypothesis as "$G$ is shifted to the right of $F$."
What happens with the null in this case? Will the null be that "$G$ is to the left of $F$ or equal to $F$?"
If so, and if I use the boundary case $F=G$ to compute the $p$-values, will the test still be conservative (in the sense that, for $\alpha < 1/2$, the probability for the $p$-values to be $\leq \alpha$ will also less than or equal to $\alpha$)?
I can't find a source that covers this.
EDIT 1:
So, I simulated the p-values in two cases:

$F=G=Uniform(0, 1)$
$F=Uniform(0.1, 1.1)$ and $G=Uniform(0, 1)$

The p-values were calculated using the null $F=G$ and alternative $F<G$ in both cases:
statistics = []
for delta in [0, 0.1]:
    rng = np.random.default_rng(11)
    for m in range(5000):
        x = rng.uniform(0 + delta, 1 + delta, size=20) # F
        y = rng.uniform(0, 1, size=20) # G
        results = scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu(x, y, alternative='less')
        if delta == 0:
            symbol = '$F=G$'
        else:
            symbol = '$F>G$'
        statistics.append([symbol, results.statistic, results.pvalue])

Here is the visualization:

If my interpretation is correct, the probability to reject a true null is equal to the nominal significance level in the case of $F=G$ and lower than it if $F>G$. Is there a way to prove this analytically for general $F$ and $G$?

As a slight aside the Bayesian Wilcoxon test, specified as a proportional odds model, makes it easy to quantify evidence for the effect being in any interval.  See here.

@Milos The issue is no different from a one-sided two sample t-test with composite null; the type I error rate is higher than the nominal significance level anywhere but at the boundary of the null space that adjoins the alternative which is where the t-test also bases its rejection region. The problem is the same, and the consequences are the same; it's a completely standard aspect of hypothesis tests with composite nulls. Draw a true rejection-rate curve for a one-sided test and you'll see it. If I get time later I may post an example.

I plotted the ECDFs of the p-values in two cases: (1) $F=G$ (F=G=Uniform(0, 1)) and (2) $F > G$ (F=Uniform(0.2, 1.2), G=Uniform(0, 1)). The p-values were calculated using the $F = G$ null and  $G > F$ alternative. The ECDF for (2) is always below that for (1), so I'd say the true type I error rate of (2) is lower than that for (1). So, did you want to say that the type I error rate is lower than the nominal significance anywhere but at the boundary, or is it higher anywhere but there (as originally stated, in which case I must be missing something :( )?

Yes, you're correct. I meant that the rejection rate under $H_0$ is lower away from the boundary of the null. I initially phrased it a different way and then failed to completely edit it. Sorry about that.

@Glen_b Chances are it's worthwhile to write an answer. Others may be interested in this and may not look up comments or decipher things said indirectly.
